# Optimizing parameters for a classification model which predicts unseen future data

Tags: classification, prediction

In my understanding, typical gridsearch (e.g. sklearn's GridSearchCV) evaluate a predefined parameter space and determines the optimal set of parameters within this space through iterating through the space and using cross validation to evaluate performance.

When a classification model (let's say a random forest) is supposed to predict unseen future data (which cannot be reasonably assumed to be similar to the training set given the time lag), it seems like caution is required in optimizing the parameter space on training data. Any suggestions on striking the right balance?

I suppose a solution would be to optimize not using cross validation, but with a validation set of future data, but this seems equally prone to overfitting on a specific time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the rub:

> predict unseen future data (which cannot be reasonably assumed to be similar to the training set given the time lag)

You *need* some measure of commonality between your training and test data. If your training data consists of dog pictures and your model perfectly predicts the dog breed portrayed, it will probably not do a very good job at determining car brands in test pictures.

So I would say that caution is not only required "in optimizing the parameter space on training data". Caution is required as in "if you want your model to deal with problem A, don't train it on problem B". Whether you then use cross-validation or some other method to avoid overfitting is really secondary.

Comment: Thanks, I see that argument, maybe I should have put the question out sharper. I am wondering whether - in excess of explicitly finding commonalities in the data - there is a cross validation type technique which would be specifically suitable for such a problem. For example, where temporal splits are progressively modelled and validation is thus always on 'future' unseen data within the training set. I see the point that optimization on set A does not help fitting set B if they are fundamentally different.

Comment: What you are describing looks like the [holdout testing used in time series forecasting](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html), which is sometimes also called "time series cross validation". The idea is that we assess our predictions on holdout data *from the very end of the history* (in "plain vanilla" cross validation, we would use *any* data point). The advantages are (1) by not chopping up the training data, we can capture autoregression and similar, and (2) our assessment is based on the newest data, which presumably is most similar to yet unseen future data.

Comment: Typically, one uses a rolling holdout set: train on data from periods $1, \dots, T$, validate on $T+1, \dots  T+h$. Then shift everything by a period: train on $2,\dots, T+1$, validate on $T+2, \dots, T+h+1$. Then shift again. This needs more historical data, but gives you more evaluations.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!